# Problems with the theorem of uniquenes and existance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For which points $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ the theorem of uniqueness and existence implies that $y'=y|y|$ has a unique solution over an interval $|x-x_{0}| \leq h$?
Because of the quarantine, I have to work this part of the course by myself but, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Which version do you know? Do you take a partial derivative or do you know what Lipschitz means?

Comment: @qbert Well, my professor wrote the proof using Lipschitz.

Comment: Ok, what can you tell me about the Lipschitz-ness of $f(y)=y|y|$?

Comment: @qbert The function y|y| is like $y^2$ for $x \geq 0$ and $-x^2$ for $x<0$ and this function isn't lipschitz, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE is of the form $y'(x)=f(x,y)$. To apply Picard-Lindelöf, you have to have a continuous function $f$ which is Lipschitz-continuous on some interval.

Lipschitz-continuity is implied by the function being in $C^1$ (differentiable with a continuous derivative) in a neighborhood of some point $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb R^2$ for $y_0\neq 0$. This directly gives you local uniqueness for $y_0\neq 0$ and any $x_0\in\mathbb R$.

Now look at the case $y_0=0$ separately.